# Who says trading data are noisy?

Tags: time-series, finance, noise, filter, white-noise

We try to denoise our time-series and model inputs with a plethora of methods like Kalman filters, EMA, Kernel filters, Splines, Beziers, etc.

But who came up with a theory that trading data is noisy at all (paper)? Don't get me wrong, I used to work with NMR and IR spectra back in the days and they were noisy as hell. Well, this was mainly due to the characteristics of the probe or detector by detecting also noise.

But as far as I know, trading data is quite accurate. Of course, there are dark pools, and some vendors which do include certain market places and some others which do not. But if the volume of a stock is 4.5M I'm pretty confident that it is not 5M or 4M. Although most of us do not believe in EMH, what if, if a stock price is actually the fair value? Then, there would not be any 'space' for noise?!

Am I missing something, or do we really blindly remove 'signal' and believe it is 'noise'?

Comment: It may all be signal if you have total, complete, bulletproof information; but that's never the case.  Phenomena driven by information you do not have must be treated as noise.

Comment: Usually by "noise" we *do not* mean "incorrect" data. Usually when talking about noise we mean something like $y = f(x) + \varepsilon$, where we want to learn about $f(x)$ and the "extra" randomness that is hardly predictable is the noise. Same as "random" phenomena does not mean "unpredictable", but it can mean simply "very complicated, depending on many factors and so easier to approximate then predict exactly".

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question seems primarily concerned with whether "noise" is a useful concept in relation to quantitative finance, which is more about the logic of stock trading than it is about statistics. quant.SE might be a better fit for this question. You can flag it  for migration if you would like.